# How to get the amount of current requested by a USB device?

Tags: windows-7, usb

Is there any USB explorer that shows this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Device Manager, you can double-click on a USB Root Hub, then go to the Power tab. You'll probably have several USB Root Hubs, so you'll have to look at each one separately to find the devices you're interested in.

[image]

( Image from an HP support page [Troubleshooting USB Connections in Windows 7](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01893385&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=4066662) )

Comment: If you use View | Devices By Connection you'll see what devices are connected to which hub. (USB devices are themselves connected to the PCI bus which is a couple of levels deep under the "ACPI ... PC" node.)